# Is topByKey scalable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

When i use topByKey with different clusters i have the same amount of time to execute this code independently of the number of slaves i use.
The RDD_distance size is beetween 10^8 and 10^12 units.

```
        parsedData.cache

        for( ind <- 1 to maxIterForYstar  ) {

        var rdd_distance = rdd_temp.cartesian(parsedData).map{ case (x,y) => (x.get_id,(y.get_vector,-Vectors.sqdist(x.get_vector,y.get_vector))) }

        var rdd_knn_bykey = rdd_distance.topByKey(k)(Ordering[(Double)].on(x=>x._2))
    }
```

So my question is about knowing if topByKey is scalable or if it is something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual code for `topByKey`:

```
@DeveloperApi
class MLPairRDDFunctions[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](self: RDD[(K, V)]) extends Serializable {
  /**
   * Returns the top k (largest) elements for each key from this RDD as defined by the specified
   * implicit Ordering[T].
   * If the number of elements for a certain key is less than k, all of them will be returned.
   *
   * @param num k, the number of top elements to return
   * @param ord the implicit ordering for T
   * @return an RDD that contains the top k values for each key
   */
  def topByKey(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[V]): RDD[(K, Array[V])] = {
    self.aggregateByKey(new BoundedPriorityQueue[V](num)(ord))(
      seqOp = (queue, item) => {
        queue += item
      },
      combOp = (queue1, queue2) => {
        queue1 ++= queue2
      }
    ).mapValues(_.toArray.sorted(ord.reverse))  // This is an min-heap, so we reverse the order.
  }
}
```

So it's the only method in `MLPairRDDFunctions`. It's a more efficient `groupByKey` with only the top `k` elements for each key retained.

A few questions to consider, which you can answer by studying the Spark web console:

- How many parallel tasks are actually executed? Some of your extra slaves might not be used.
- Where is the time really being spent? For example, is the `cartesian` product actually the most expensive? Could you use caching more effectively? Also, it looks like `rdd_distance` can be computed once, before the `for` expression, or is this just a simplified example?